# Whats making my mouseover and react setState slow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It feels like any sort of "click and drag" type of action I create feel kind of... well choppy. Like it's stuttering. I know when I console log the data is instant from the event, but the delays within the update to state are what makes it seem slower.

Here is a very simple example:

```
const TestMouseOver = () => {
  const [pos, setPos] = useState();

  const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    setPos({
      x: e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft,
      y: e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop,
    })
  }
  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    setPos({
      x: e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft,
      y: e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop,
    })
  }
  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={(event) => onMouseDown(event)}
      onMouseMove={(event) => onMouseMove(event)}
      onMouseUp={() => setPos(null)}
    >
      {pos && <MoveBox position={pos} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

within `MoveBox` I take the `pos` and just set the div's absolute css as the position (styled-components). Nothing to fancy in there. It *works* but it's laggy and slow.

Should I be attempted to build some sort of lerp or animation to go to last know cord to smooth out the position update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MouseEvents are not throttled : everytime your mouse move, it will call your `setState` functions. That can happen hundreds of time a second, causing React to rerender as often which is by far suboptimal.

At max tempo, React shouldn't rerender more than every frame of 16ms to ensure smooth 60 FPS animations on your website.

You need to throttle these events by using [lodash.throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.throttle) for example and register a callback using `useCallback`.

Sample code :

```
const handleMouseMove = useCallback(lodash.throttle((e) => {
    setPos({
      x: e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft,
      y: e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop,
    });
}, 16), []);

return (
    <div onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}>{...}</div>
)
```

Notice the `16` as the second argument of `lodash.throttle` : it ensures the function doesn't get called more often than every 16ms.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach you should consider would be to use a browser native api requestAnimationFrame

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

This is how it would be implemented for your specific case

```
const TestMouseOver = () => {
  const [pos, setPos] = useState();
  let ticking = false;

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    requestTick(event);
  }

  function onMouseDown(event) {
    requestTick(event);
  }

  function requestTick(event) {
    if (!ticking) {
      requestAnimationFrame(update(event));
    }
    ticking = true;
  }

  function update(e) {
    // reset the tick so we can capture next mouseevent
    ticking = false;

    setPos((prevState) => ({
      x: e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft,
      y: e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop,
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={(event) => onMouseDown(event)}
      onMouseMove={(event) => onMouseMove(event)}
      onMouseUp={() => setPos(null)}
    >
      {pos && <MoveBox position={pos} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

PROS:

- No need of any external libraries
- Executes on a frame basis. So, UI behaviour is smooth.

CONS:

- Does not have IE9 support
- Cannot define throttle duration because it is coupled to framerate

**How it works:**
Basically, using a variable and requestAnimationFrame method, we make sure that the state is updated at the rate of frame update